# Why this object doesn't detect the father class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have the following classes:

The `Automata` Class

```
#ifndef Automata_H
#define Automata_H

class Automata {

protected:
   // ...
public:
   virtual DFA* dfaEquivalent() {}
   // ....
};
```

The `DFA` class that inherits from `Automata`

```
#include "Automata.hpp"
#ifndef DFA_H
#define DFA_H

class DFA : public Automata 
{
private:
public:
   DFA() {}
};
```

And finnaly that inherits from `DFA`:

```
#include "DFA.hpp"

#ifndef _NFA_H
#define _NFA_H

class NFA : public DFA
{
private:
public:
   NFA() { }
   DFA* dfaEquivalent()
   {}
};
#endif
```

The problem comes when I have an instance of `NFA` and I want to call `dfaEquivalent`, and the compiler says the following :

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from DFA.hpp:1:0,
                 from NFA.hpp:1,
                 from Comparador.hpp:5,
                 from main.cpp:2:
Automata.hpp:96:13: error: ‘DFA’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘DFA_H’?
     virtual DFA* dfaEquivalent(){}
             ^~~
             DFA_H
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

What's the mistake I am committing with inheritance?

Comment: `Automata` doesn't know anything about `DFA`. Why do you want to return `DFA*` instead of `Automata*`?

Comment: Side note: don't include files outside your header guards. Include them inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a forward declaration in the base class (i.e. in `Automata.h` ) header.

The compiler does not know what is the type `DFA` at the time, it compiles the  `Automata.h` header (i.e. in the virtual function of `Automata` class)

```
virtual DFA* dfaEquivalent(){}
//      ^^^^--> unknown type
```

Since it is a pointer to a type `DFA`, providing a forward declaration for `DFA` in the `Automata.h` the header will solve the issue.

```
#ifndef Automata_H
#define Automata_H

class DFA; // forward declaration

class Automata 
{
public:
   virtual DFA* dfaEquivalent() {}
   // ...code
};
#endif
```

---

As a side note, have a look: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors). Your `Automata` might need one if you store the child class object to pointer to `Automata`.